# Hartshorne II.7.10: Is there any error in my proof that every Zariski-locally trivial $\Bbb P^n$-bundle is relative Proj of a locally free sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification

In Hartshorne's exercise II.7.10 part (c), we're asked to do the following, where $X$ is a noetherian scheme: $\renewcommand{\PP}{\Bbb P}\renewcommand{\cE}{\mathcal{E}}\renewcommand{\cO}{\mathcal{O}}\renewcommand{\cL}{\mathcal{L}}\renewcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}$

> Assume that $X$ is regular, and show that every $\PP^n$-bundle $P$ over $X$ is isomorphic to $\PP(\cE)$ for some locally free sheaf $\cE$ on $X$.
> [*Hint*: Let $U\subset X$ be an open set such that $\pi^{-1}(U)\cong U\times\PP^n$, and let $\cL_0$ be the invertible sheaf $\cO(1)$ on $U\times\PP^n$.
> Show that $\cL_0$ extends to an invertible sheaf $\cL$ on $P$.
> Then show that $\pi_*\cL=\cE$ is a locally free sheaf on $X$ and that $P\cong \PP(\cE)$.]
> Can you weaken the hypothesis '$X$ regular'?

Here's Hartshorne's definition of a projective bundle from earlier in the question:

> By analogy with the definition of a vector bundle (Ex. 5.18), define the notion of a *projective* $n$-*space bundle* over $X$, as a scheme $P$ with a morphism $\pi:P\to X$ such that $P$ is locally isomorphic to $U\times \PP^n$, $U\subset X$ open, and the transition automorphisms on $\Spec A\times\PP^n$ are given by $A$-linear automorphisms of the homogeneous coordinate ring $A[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$ (e.g., $x'_i=\sum a_{ij}x_j$, $a_{ij}\in A$).

I do not understand the hint about extending $\cL_0$ to an invertible sheaf on $P$. My attempt so far seems to sort of blow by this, and I'm not confident it's correct - if it were true, it would seem that I can completely remove the regularity condition, which seems a little drastic (I would expect that we at least need something like regular in codimension one or locally factorial). Here's what I have so far:

Take $X$ connected (else go component-by-component). Cover $X$ by affine schemes $U_i$ so that $\pi^{-1}(U_i)\cong U_i\times\PP^n$, by the definition of a $\PP^n$-bundle. Let $\cL_i=\cO(1)$ on $U_i\times\PP^n$: then $(\pi|_{U_i\times\PP^n})_*\cL_i$ is a free module of rank $n+1$ on each $U_i$. For any $\Spec A$ which lies in both $U_i$ and $U_j$, we get that $(\pi|_{\Spec A\times\PP^n})_*\cL_i\cong(\pi|_{\Spec A\times\PP^n})_*\cL_j$ by the $A$-linear automorphism restricted to the degree-one piece of the homogeneous coordinate ring. We can then use these isomorphisms to glue the $(\pi|_{U_i\times\PP^n})_*\cL_i$ in to a locally free sheaf $\cE$ on $X$. Then $\PP(\cE)\cong P$ as the gluing data for $\PP(\cE)$ is exactly the gluing data coming from $P$.

Like I said, I'm worried I'm making an error (especially because this problem is starred, and my solution seems too short). Can anyone point out where this error might be, or assuage my concerns?

Comment: In https://mathoverflow.net/a/306885/172450, Sasha gives an incomplete example without proof that should indicate that regularity is needed.

Comment: Regarding your proof, the line where I lost it a bit is: "For any $\operatorname{Spec} A$ ... homogeneous coordinate ring."

Comment: Dear @JeroenvanderMeer, thanks for the comments - I don't understand Sasha's example yet, but hopefully I will soon. My argument in the line you refer to is a consequence of Hartshorne prop II.7.11: If $X$ is a noeth. scheme with $E$ a locally free sheaf on $X$, $\pi:\Bbb P(E)\to X$ is the projection and $S=Sym(E)$, then $S\cong \bigoplus \pi_*\mathcal{O}_P(n)$ as graded rings. Thus $\pi_*\mathcal{O}_P(1)\cong E$, so I think that the $A$-linear isom. of $\Bbb P^n_A$ should give me an $A$-linear isomorphism between the free $A$-modules which are the pushforwards of the two different $O(1)$s.

Comment: I see! I wish I could help further, but I really don't know.